# How do i vaidate header columns name in .csv file using Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

How do i vaidate header columns name in .csv file using Angular

I am trying to check weather all the header names are present in uploaded .csv file or not, If the file contains extra headers or invalid headers, we should throw error in div tag.

Here is my code, but doesn't seems to be working, please help me on this.

I am not sure, how to check if the .csv file contains extra Header column or not - please suggest me

```
bulkUploadField: any;
convertFile(csvfile: any) {   
this.bulkUploadField = csvfile.target.files[0];
let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();   reader.readAsText(this.bulkUploadField);  
let lastIndex = 0; 
this.csvData = [];
reader.onload = (e) => {  
  console.log('csv file uploaded and coming to onload')
  let csv: any = reader.result;
  let allTextLines = csv.split(/\n/);  
  this.csvHeader = allTextLines[0].split(',');
  if(!(this.csvHeader[0].toLowerCase().trim()  == 'HEADERPolicy Number' &&
  this.csvHeader[1].toLowerCase().trim()  == 'Current State')&&
  this.csvHeader[1].toLowerCase().trim()  == 'Current Company')&&
  this.csvHeader[1].toLowerCase().trim()  == 'Main amount')&&
  this.csvHeader[1].toLowerCase().trim()  == 'Interest rate')&&
  this.csvHeader[1].toLowerCase().trim()  == 'Total Amount')
  )
  {
    this.toast.show('Uploaded data is not in proper format','error');
    return;
  }
  }
 }
```

Comment: count the number of columns and compare to expected

Comment: also consider refactoring all those checks into a validate() method

Comment: Compare the length of the ```csvHeader``` array (which contains the header names from the csv file) with the length of an array of expected header names. If the lengths are not equal, it means the file contains extra header columns. You can also [check this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/237912/parsing-csv-header-for-validation) just for your reference.

Comment: Thank you all for your input, I will try to implement the same as per your suggestion